# Maximum singular value of a random $\pm 1$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random-matrices, eigenvalues, singular-values

Define a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ such that each element is independently and randomly chosen with probability $\frac 12$ to be either $+1$, or $-1$. Do you know any result in the literature that talks about properties of this kind of matrices?

I have seen that there are some results for other kind of random matrices (for example matrices whose entries are i.i.d. Gaussian.) but not for this simple matrix of $\pm 1$.

I would be interested for example on the distribution of the $\sigma_{\max}(A)$, but not in an asymptotic regime, as $m$, $n$ are finite numbers and usually small in my case.

Thank you very much for any pointer or any thoughts.

Comment: **How** small are $m$ and $n$? Less than 10? Less than 100?

Comment: Maybe the standard $\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n}$ bound applies here too.

Comment: Hi,

thank you very much for your comments. $m$ and $n$ are usually less than 10. 

Do you have a paper in mind that talks about the $\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n}$ bound?
Thank you,
best,
Alex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/papers/non-asymptotic-rmt-plain.pdf
Theorem 5.39 (page 23) gives a non-asymptotic upper bound on the largest singular value

Comment: The link is broken, the last indexed version can be found on [the archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20180721063651/http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/papers/non-asymptotic-rmt-plain.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, it's relatively easy to simulate these in Mathematica, via

```
Manipulate[
 Histogram[
  N[SingularValueList[ 2 RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {m, n}] - 1, 1][[
      1]]] & /@ Range[10^power]], {m, 1, 10, 1}, {n, 1, 10, 
  1}, {power, 1, 6, 1}]
```

I've been playing around with it, and this

[image: histogram]

is a histogram for 1,000,000 tries with $m=9$, $n=5$ for the five different singular values (each in a different colour). I'm intrigued by the peaks - were you expecting that? There is also a significant portion of matrices with one zero singular value, but I am unsure whether it is due to numerical artifacts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time to code this! It was very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome! Mathematica code is normally deceptively simple but this was quite straightforward. Plus, it helped me crystallize the Random[]&/@Range[] trick which had been annoyingly floating around my mind with a "there has to be a simple way" kind of taunt.

Comment: Any matrix with two rows which are multiples of each other will automatically have a $0$ singular value.  This accounts for most of the peak you see at $0$ (each pair of rows matches for about $3900$ matrices and there's $10$ pairs of rows), but disappears as $\min\{m,n\}$ tends to infinity.  

Comment: @KevinPCostello: yes, that sounds simple enough. Why is it separate from the rest of the minimum-singular-value histogram, though? if you fix $m$ and take $n\rightarrow\infty$, does it "leak out" to positive singular values? I guess I'm asking why it is so much more unlikely that a random matrix be "almost singular" than it be just plain singular, which kind of makes sense since it's hard to build a very slim parallelogram with only integer coordinates but you might build a plane now and then. Is my intuition right?

Comment: In a sense, "local" configurations (those involving only a couple rows) can only get you so close to $0$:  If you look at, say, $|| \{1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 \} A||$, it's either going to be $0$ or at least $1$, meaning that this can't be the cause of a positive singular value smaller than $2^{-1/2}$.  Intuitively, a $0$ singular value (which requires only $1$ row to go wrong) is much easier than a very small positive singular value (which requires $2$ or more rows to go wrong), though this is far from a rigorous proof.  

Comment: (continued) Even if you let both $m$ and $n$ go to infinity, but at different rates (say $m/n \rightarrow c<1$), the smallest singular value will with high probability grow be within a constant of the largest (Bai and Yin, "Limit of the smallest eigenvalue of a large dimensional covariance matrix", see also Rudelson and Vershynin's "The smallest singular value of a random rectangular matrix" )

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for pointing out this dead link. Boy, this thread is *old* - it's pretty scary how dust accumulates on what used to be pretty reasonable dates.

Answer (score 3):

In relation to the first question, a recent breakthrough result of Konstantin Tikhomirov answers affirmatively an old conjecture attributed to Von Neumann, namely that for $M_n$, an $n\times n$ random matrix with independent $\pm 1$ entries

$$\mathbb{P}(M_{n}\ \text{is singular})=\left(\frac{1}{2}+o(1)\right)^n.$$

Here is the [pre-print](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.09016.pdf) and a relevant entry in Gil Kalai's blog can be found [here](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2019/02/02/konstantin-tikhomrov-the-probability-that-a-bernoulli-matrix-is-singular/).

Comment: A comment on Gil's blog notes this earlier claim of the same result: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05283.pdf .  Any reason to discount that?